# Backup server for a NAS with web interface

Tags: web, backup, nas, synology

I'm evaluating the features of a full-fledged backup server for my NAS (synology). I need

- FTP access (backup remote sites)
- SSH/SCP access (backup remote server)
- web interface (in order to monitor each backup job)
- automatic mail alerting if jobs fail
- lightweight software (no mysql, sqlite ok)
- optional: S3/Glacier support (as target)
- optional: automatic long-term storage after a given time (ie local disk for 3 months, Glacier after that)

seems like biggest player are Amanda, Bacula and duplicity (likewise)

Any suggestion?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Before jumping on the full server backups, please clarify these questions:

1. Backup software's are agent and non agent based, which one do you want to use?
2. Are you interested to go for open source or proprietary software?
3. Determine your source and destination are they in the same LAN or in the Internet. Try to get the picture of the bandwidth between source and destination and the volume of data getting backed up?
4. Also if you are interested try to know gui requirements and various other os platform support for backup software.
5. Importantly try to know the mail notification configuration.

Presently am setting one for my project and so far have installed bacula-v7.0.5 with webmin as gui. Trying the same config in the amazon cloud utilizing s3 as storage by mounting s3fs into the ec2 instance.

My bacula software is a free community version.Haven't explored the mail notification until now.